# sniffing serial port - jpnevulator sniffs only some bytes

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

I use jpnevulator to sniff an application which reads a serial port:

```
jpnevulator --tty /dev/ttyS0 --read
```

Let's assume that the following bytes are sent to the serial port: A B C D E. Sometimes jpnevulator prints only bytes: A C E whereas the application gets bytes B D.

jpnevulator should print bytes: A B C D E and the application also should get all bytes: A B C D E. What is wrong ? Should I run jpnevulator with some option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with `jpnevulator`, but in general: If you have two applications reading from a single tty, then only one application will get the data.

If you want to duplicate the data, you have to create a second (or third) tty, and let the application read from it.

One way to do it is to use something like [ttybus](https://github.com/danielinux/ttybus). You can then attach `jpnevulator` to one of the new ttys, and your application to another.

Another way is to use `socat` with `-x` or `-v`, e.g.

```
socat -x PTY,link=/tmp/ptya /dev/ttyS0
```

and then point your application to `/tmp/ptya`, while `socat` dumps the traffic in hex to `stderr`.